# Do I need to be concerned using the Git Bash on Windows with Shellshock?

Tags: bash, security, malware, git-bash, shellshock

I use the Git Bash on a Windows 8.1 machine.

Do I need to be concerned by `Shellshock`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple to test for yourself.

#### CVE-2014-6271

CVE-2014-6271 is the original shellshock bug.  To see if you are vulnerable, run this code at the bash command prompt:

```
env VAR='() { :;}; echo Bash is vulnerable!' bash -c "echo Bash Test"
```

If the output is:

```
Bash Test
```

Then you are fine.  If, on the other hand, you see:

```
Bash is vulnerable!
Bash Test
```

Then your `bash` is vulnerable.

#### CVE-2014-7169

There is a [newer related vulnerability](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1212303).  To test for this one, run this code:

```
env X='() { (a)=>\' sh -c "echo date"; cat echo
```

If you see the following output:

```
date
cat: echo: No such file or directory
```

Then you are fine.

All versions of bash up through 4.3, which is the current version, were vulnerable to shellshock.  Since patches keep getting updated, updating your version is probably a good idea.

#### Who is vulnerable?

[According to Qualys](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/laws-of-vulnerabilities/2014/09/24/bash-shellshock-vulnerability), *remote* exploitation of shellshock may be possible in the following situations:

> - Apache server using mod_cgi or mod_cgid are affected if CGI scripts are either written in bash, or spawn subshells. Such subshells
>     are implicitly used by system/popen in C, by os.system/os.popen in
>     Python, system/exec in PHP (when run in CGI mode), and open/system in
>     Perl if a shell is used (which depends on the command string)
> - ForceCommand is used in sshd configs to provide limited command execution capabilities for remote users. This flaw can be used to
>     bypass that and provide arbitrary command execution. Some Git and
>     Subversion deployments use such restricted shells. Regular use of
>     OpenSSH is not affected because users already have shell access.
> - DHCP clients invoke shell scripts to configure the system, with values taken from a potentially malicious server. This would allow
>     arbitrary commands to be run, typically as root, on the DHCP client
>     machine.
> - Various daemons and SUID/privileged programs may execute shell scripts with environment variable values set / influenced by the user,
>     which would allow for arbitrary commands to be run.
> - Any other application which is hooked onto a shell or runs a shell script as using bash as the interpreter. Shell scripts which do
>     not export variables are not vulnerable to this issue, even if they
>     process untrusted content and store it in (unexported) shell variables
>     and open subshells.

To be vulnerable on Windows, however, one would have to be using a version of one of the above service that invokes `bash`.

Comment: Cheers John, the second script just gives me a syntax error for the first `=`.

Comment: This answers the question "Is my bash buggy". It doesn't answer the question "am I vulnerable". You're vulnerable if you have a buggy bash which can be started automatically by a service which passes unvalidated environment variables, such as a webserver with a CGI handler *which invokes bash*. That's pretty unlikely on a Windows machine, but certainly not impossible.

Comment: @rici Good point.  I added a section on potential vulnerabilities.

Comment: @BanksySan In that case, I would suggest updating.

Comment: This answer really should focus more on the last part and explain why or why not the vulnerability is relevant to Windows. It's *very* unlikely that anything in Windows depends on Bash or even executes privileged commands through it.